# NSIS auto accept dialog in silent mode

Tags: nsis

I have an nsis installer with a custom dialog within that has an Accept button but when i run it in silent mode , it does not accept the dialog. How to make it auto clicking accept silently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If your dialog was a standard `MessageBox`, simply add the `/SD button_id_to_use` parameter to the [`MessageBox` instruction](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.4.15) to tell NSIS what is the choice to use in silent mode:

  ```
  MessageBox MB_YESNO "Accept?" /SD IDNO IDNO Skipped
  ```
- if your dialog is a custom page, the problem is that in silent mode, no pages are involved at all (even hidden), and no page callback are trigerred. You need to check `IfSilent` and call the logic that is triggered by the Accept button separately from either the `.onInit` or a section.

Comment: You did not shown your code... You need to add `/SD` with the ID of the button to choose in silent mode, **and you need to put it between the message and the list of the buttons**

Comment: but it's not a messagebox it's a dialog

Comment: sorry, I have missed the fact it is a custom dialog, not a messagebox. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
IfSilent Accepted
MessageBox MB_YESNO "Accept?" IDNO Skipped
Accepted:
// some code when accepted

Skipped:
```

Comment: no need to simulate with a `IfSilent` test: the `/SD` parameter of `MessageBox` is dedicated to silent mode

Comment: right, but that's only available for the standard messagebox command - not for the custom messagebox plugin

Comment: yes, but in your example you show how to skip a standard MessageBox :)

Comment: true, pure laziness. anyway, if you still consider using that custom messagebox plugin, you probably shouldn't: http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=2784163&postcount=6